# What AMI is launched on Amazon's elastic mapreduce instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I haven't been able to find out what AMI runs on Amazon's elastic mapreduce instances. You can't specify one, but can customize the mapreduce instances by running a boostrap action. However, I'd like to know what I'm starting with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently one is:

- ami-d6c232bf: us-east1, 32-bit

It appears that the specific **AMI changes** over time (and certainly between regions).

The answer can be found at any time or region by:

1. Running `curl http://169.254.169.254/2011-01-01/meta-data/ami-id` after connecting with ssh to one of the EMR clusters you create.
2. Checking the EC2 management console or CLI tools from that region. Your **EMR instances show up as EC2 instances**.

It also appears that it is possible to launch these into your own EC2 or VPC. I have verified that (at least with the image listed above), you can SSH into it after launching into EC2. I have no idea what will happen to hadoop if you do this or if this access will be discontinued at some point.

Comment: FYI, the current (2012-05-14) EMR instance is ami-a9b362c0.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/faqs/#dev-9). it's running Debian Lenny. I couldn't find the actual AMI.